# How to read special character delimiter present in csv files through python?

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I have a CSV file which has delimiter at the end of every line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEin9.png)

However, I am unable to read it in python- I want to validate if that special char exists after every line:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COd5M.png)

I want to be able to read that special char while reading in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special characters you consider it is:

**CR = [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)**

**LF = [Line Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)**

You can read the links that what is meaning. How they represent in programming languages? CR+LF equals to '\n' so you have read it already.

Comment: CR+LF is `'\r\n'` but `open(..., 'r')` opens the file in universal lines mode is enabled. `help(open)` says "Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller."

Comment: Thanks alot! It helped.